# convert integer(with a value greater than 9) to character

Tags: c

I am trying to convert an integer(greater than 9 as below 9 it converts easily by the below process) to character. But after conversion I get some characters like '?'..below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

     int i = 15;
     char c;
     c=i+'0';

     printf("%c", c);

     return 0;
    }


output: ?
Expected output: 15
```

Comment: Why do you expect the output to be 15?

Comment: You don't want to convert it into character, you want to convert it into a string. For that the net is full of help. As you can see, your expected result has *two* characters in it.

Comment: For an explanation of what's happening, check out the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: yes I am understanding why its giving '?' as output. I want to just get '15' in variable c. @stakx yes..I want that solution

Comment: @AbhishekSinha  You can't get it in a single char variable . You need an array .

Comment: *"I want to just get '15' in variable c"*. You can't because you have added `'0'` (ASCII 48) to it.

Answer (score 2):

"15" are two characters. You would have to convert it digit by digit.

Answer (score 2):

It won't work because you have two digit number. Such simple convertion will work for numbers 0-9 but not for greater. You can use [itoa function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/). Example of use is in the link provided

Comment: `itoa` isn't a standard function, this might not work.

Comment: yup, you're right but it is almost always included in the stblib.h headers. It is very rare situation nowadays that it is not :)

Answer (score 1):

Making a string from an integer is not possible directly, the reason why this works

```
int number = 2;
char character = number + '0';
fprintf(stdout, "%c\n", character);
```

is because `'0'` is the ascii value that represents the number `0` which is `48`, and since they appear in order in the ascii table, adding the number to it will give you the ascii value of the number.

But `15` consists of 2 ascii values, a quick way to perform the conversion is to use an array, like this

```
char string[3];
int number;
int result;
number = 15;
result = snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "%d", number);
if (result >= sizeof(string))
    fprintf(stdout, "the string was truncated, there is no space to store the result");
else if (result < 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "an error occurred\n");
else
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 digits which is why printing it out like that doesn't work. If you want to convert the int to a string use `sprintf` :

```
int i= 15;
char str[15];
snprintf(str, 15, "%d", i); // str now contains "15"
```

Comment: Use `snprintf()` instead.